# Invoke at runtime the customization panel of a Telerik's RadLayoutControl

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I'm using the **[RadLayoutControl](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/layoutcontrol-overview.html)** control from **[Telerik UI for Winforms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)**.

As familiarized users will know, if the user press right-click on the blank space of the layout at runtime, it will appear this button:

[image]

Then this panel:

[image]

What I would like to know is, which is the method that I need to call to make appear that customization panel at any time?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
radLayoutControl1.ShowCustomizeDialog();
```